# Problems with compiz on 16.04

Tags: unity, compiz

After last packages update on Ubuntu 16.04 I got some problems with compiz (maybe with compiz, maybe with another package). 
When screen is locked and I Press Alt + Shift to change keyboard locale, x-server drops down (panel in the top disappears, screen turns off and then turns on). After that, when I logged in, I get Ubuntu internal error dialog with error in `compiz-core` package:

```
compiz crashed with SIGABRT in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
```

I tried to reinstall compiz, compiz-core, backing up and hold all compiz* packages in synaptic before update, reset dconf -- but that is not work for me. Last time when I reset dconf and run

```
setsid compiz --replace
```

I got

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call> >'  what():  call to empty boost::function
```

in terminal.
All in all, when I press Alt + Shift on locked screen I get error. And there are two more additional problems: 
1) When I use any online video player (on youtube, for example), and go to full-screen mode, my cursor does not hide.
2) I am not allowed to drag windows between workspaces.

Hope for your help.
UPD: [Some information from .crash file](http://pastebin.com/ztqHbcPZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last Ubuntu update fixed it.