# Ubuntu 16.04 Problem in switching between languages in login screen

Tags: 16.04, login, shortcut-keys, language-support

After installing 16.04, I have a problem in login in after the Ubuntu goes to login screen - if the language was set to a different language rather than English, and I try to switch back to English (with a shortcut I've set : left ALT + left SHIFT), the screen flashes but does not allow me to log in. I have to switch between languages by pressing the button on the top right corner, and only then I can log in. Afterwards it gives an error message of this sort:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem (https://askubuntu.com/questions/808822/problems-with-compiz-on-16-04). But there are no ideas how to solve it. Looks like a bug

Comment: @danielleontiev: Probably https://launchpad.net/bugs/1605012, which will be fixed soon. The fixed unity package is available in xenial-proposed.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, can your describe, how to install this fixed package now from xenial-proposed?

Comment: @danielleontiev: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I've added xenial-proposed, but there aren't fixed unity package

Comment: @danielleontiev: **unity 7.4.0+16.04.20160801.2-0ubuntu1** should be there. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity (did you run `sudo apt update` after having enabled -proposed?)